# Change directory after unziping

Tags: linux, unzip

I am making a script that allow's me to unzip a given file. My problem is that i don't now how to change directory to the directory just created by the unzip process.
I tried with this command, but it's not working: `SITE_DIRECTORY="$(ls -dt */ | head -1)"`

Any idea on how to get the name of the directory just extracted ?

Edit: Now i got to `SITE_DIRECTORY=unzip $SITE_NAME | grep 'creating:' | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f5-`

But a new problem arise: the unzip command does not extract all the files.
New ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was the following commands:

```
unzip $SITE_NAME >output.txt
SITE_DIRECTORY=$(cat output.txt | grep -m1 'creating:' |  cut -d' ' -f5-)
rm output.txt
```

Thanks goes to [Evan @ Unzip File which directory was created](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71080/67343)

Comment: still have a problem. the unzip does not extract all the files.

Answer (score 1):

If the directory is known, you could

```
unzip -j yourzip.zip -d /path/to/dir && cd /path/to/dir
```

Extra info from [man page](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html) (`j` option)

> -j junk paths. The archive's directory structure is not recreated; all files are deposited in the extraction directory (by default, the
>   current one).

Comment: My zip archive already contains a directory. I don't want to have directory inside directory and I don't know what's the name of the directory extracted.

Comment: Edited my answer. -j option could be the missing puzzle piece.